# How to create accounts for users on network?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking

In schools, colleges etc.. there are some software installed that only allows access to internet if a user and pass is entered. Ex - Cyberoam

I have seen this in colleges, the network admin manages different accounts, creates new ones and grants specific access to some users, blocks certain websites etc..

This is what I want to do. I have got a router and lots of other devices that connect via Wifi. I want to implement a system like a Cyberoam, a basic system would do, i.e, atleast it asks for username and password before allowing user to access Internet. I'm not talking about the basic Wifi password, what I want to do is that once user logs onto the network with the correct password then after opening browser or any internet software/app, user should be redirected to a page that asks for user and pass that is allocated to them.

Unfortunately, I don't have much knowledge regarding managing networks so I haven't done anything to show you.

Note:- *I'm not sure if this question is good fit for this site or it belongs to other site within Stack Exchange.*

Comment: This is usually a feature of hiqh-quality proffessional routers such as Cisco or Ruckus. You will need to pay at least 500$ for such router though.

Comment: So you have no knowlege or very limited knowlege on the subject.  You also don't indicate what software you are going to implement specifically.  So what exatly is your question?

Answer (score 0):

The term you're looking for is "captive portal". Although this is typically a feature of enterprise-grade APs, it can be added to consumer-grade APs via open source firmware distros like OpenWrt, DD-WRT, etc.